# Buffers and URL encoding in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I url-decode and url-encode Buffers in node.js? I have ciphertext bytes coming in as url-encoded and I need to decode them and decrypt them, so the buffer will not be guaranteed to have all standard UTF-8 characters.

Here is what i've tried, but the decoded result does not match the original:

```
> foo = Buffer.from('deadbeef', 'hex')
<Buffer de ad be ef>
> fooEnc = encodeURIComponent(foo)
'%DE%AD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD'
> fooDec = decodeURIComponent(fooEnc)
'ޭ��'
> Buffer.from(fooDec).toString('hex')
'deadefbfbdefbfbd'
```

Comment: The function `encodeURIComponent()` is defined for strings.  Why do you need it for `Buffer`s?  Can't you just use the original 'deadbeef' string?

Comment: deadbeef is hex encoded, like I said, the data I'm expecting is not standard UTF-8 so I can't use strings, e.g. `0xdeadbeef` would be ��'. Also see edit.

Comment: Well that's my question: Why not hex encoded or base64?

Comment: Oh, I see, yes great question! Well unfortunately, I don't have access to the code that sends the data, so I can't change the format of the data that I receive. Base64 would be much better.

Comment: Try this answer: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/3623

Comment: So then your question is a bit misleading – you don't have a Buffer and don't want to encode it, but you get the string '%DE%AD%BE%EF' and want to decode it to a buffer. Then the example isn't the best because I guess that not all bytes are encoded as %_xx_ but just those that are not in the ASCII range and are not valid in an URL.  Otherwise it would be simply `Buffer.from('%DE%AD%BE%EF'.replace(/%/g, ''), 'hex')`

Comment: Is `%DE%AD%BE%EF` how `0xdeadbeef` would be url-encoded? I'm sorry I don't even have an example of text I'm trying to decode, I just made something up. In that case, that's much easier than i thought.

Comment: `fooEnc = encodeURIComponent(foo)` is the problem. You're treating a string as if it's encoded in UTF-8, forcing it to implicitly pad invalid codepoints in your binary string, causing data loss. Don't implicitly call `.toString('utf8')` on a buffer containing non-UTF-8 encoded characters, because you won't be able to recover the original string again.

Comment: @JBaczuk that depends if it should be encoded in little or big endian byte order.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some functions I came up with to convert between url-encoding and Buffers (for any byte value including non-standard utf8):

```
const isUrlSafe = (char) => {
  return /[a-zA-Z0-9\-_~.]+/.test(char)
}

const urlEncodeBytes = (buf) => {
  let encoded = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
    const charBuf = Buffer.from('00', 'hex')
    charBuf.writeUInt8(buf[i])
    const char = charBuf.toString()
    // if the character is safe, then just print it, otherwise encode
    if (isUrlSafe(char)) {
      encoded += char
    } else {
      encoded += `%${charBuf.toString('hex').toUpperCase()}`
    }
  }
  return encoded
}

const urlDecodeBytes = (encoded) => {
  let decoded = Buffer.from('')
  for (let i = 0; i < encoded.length; i++) {
    if (encoded[i] === '%') {
      const charBuf = Buffer.from(`${encoded[i + 1]}${encoded[i + 2]}`, 'hex')
      decoded = Buffer.concat([decoded, charBuf])
      i += 2
    } else {
      const charBuf = Buffer.from(encoded[i])
      decoded = Buffer.concat([decoded, charBuf])
    }
  }
  return decoded
}
```

Examples:

```
> const buf = Buffer.from('4142432b', 'hex')
> const encoded = urlEncodeBytes(buf)
'ABC%2B'

> const encoded = 'ABC%2B'
> const buf = urlDecodeBytes(encoded)
<Buffer 41 42 43 2b>
```